# Polymorphism in Dafny

Tags: polymorphism, dafny

I am trying to do polymorphism in Dafny but I can't make it work. I didn't find any documentation to help me with this. Here is the code: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/uQ1w

```
trait Atom {
  var Leaf? : bool;
}

class Leaf extends Atom {
  constructor() {
    this.Leaf? := true;
  }
}

class Node extends Atom {
  var left : Atom;

  constructor() {
    this.Leaf? := false;
    this.left := new Leaf();
  }
}

method Main() {
  var root := new Node();
  root.left := new Node();

  root.left.left := new Node();
}
```

The error:

```
Dafny 2.1.1.10209
stdin.dfy(24,12): Error: member left does not exist in trait Atom
1 resolution/type errors detected in stdin.dfy
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression `root.left` has type `Atom` (since that is the type of `left` field in `Node` class). Therefore, the type system doesn't know whether the object pointed by `root.left` is a `Leaf` or a `Node` and, in particular, it cannot ensure that this object has a `left` attribute.

You can circumvent this by assigning the left child to a variable first, and then accessing its `next` attribute:

```
method Main() {
  var root := new Node();

  // root_l is inferred to have type 'Node' instead of 'Atom'  
  var root_l := new Node();
  root.left := root_l;

  // Here root_l has type Node, so it has a 'left' attribute.
  root_l.left := new Node();
}
```

In an object-oriented language (e.g. Java), this can also be solved with the help of downcastings (for instance `((Node)root.left).left := new Node();`, but I don't know whether such castings are supported in Dafny.

Comment: Your example works, but doesn't clarify how should I do some things. Check `displayTree` in the same example https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/iV0U .

Comment: Implementing a method in the top of the hierarchy (`Atom`) that distinguishes cases on whether `this` is an instance of one child (`Leaf`) or another (`Node`) is not recommended practice in any OO language. You can declare `display()` abstract (i.e. without implementation) in `Atom` and override it in each subclass with its specific implementation. See https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/6wslZp for an example.

Answer (score 0):

For this particular example, it would make sense to use a `datatype`:

```
datatype Atom = Leaf | Node(left: Atom)

method Main() {
  var root := Atom.Node(Atom.Node(Atom.Leaf));
}
```

The compiler provides predicates `atom.Leaf?` and `atom.Node?` for the two kinds of `Atom`. For example, `root.Node?` is `true`.

Comment: I am already using `datatype` and I want to refactor my code.

Comment: How do you recommend to structure the code if I want a lot of functions specific to Node and Atom? Like `displayTree` in this example: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/iV0U

Comment: @AndriciCezar Use `match`. It's nice; your code ends up much shorter and it just says what you mean. Here's an example: https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/jFtz

Comment: `datatype` isn't good for everything, but when the set of possible subclasses is smallish and "closed" (unlikely to change often), it really shines. It isn't a brand new idea in Dafny; languages like ML, Haskell, and Rust have the same thing, under several different names.